# How do I return the json data from a multi table?

Tags: c#, arrays, web-services, linq-to-sql, getjson

I am using C# web service + Linq to SQL Classes + Return JSON Data.

For example my table:

[image: table]

Data from this table return JSON:

[image: JSON]

I want to make this application using C#?

Comment: you can create a viewmodel class in C# which has `Badge` and `VoleType` as properties and deserialize your JSON to that C# object using `HttpContent.ReadAsync()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create New Class for Combine Class:

```
public class BadgeVoleModel
{
    public List<Badge> BadgeList = new List<Badge>();

    public List<VoleType> VoleTypeList = new List<VoleType>();
}
```

Create Method (return string) for handle get data from DataContext and populate data to BadgeVoleModel, and call from Controller that method.

```
    public string GetData()
    {
        var data = new Models.BadgeVoleModel();

        data.BadgeList = db.Badges.ToList();
        data.VoleTypeList = db.VoleTypes.ToList();

        var result = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data);

        return result;
    }
```

And for Deserialize Data:

```
    public Models.BadgeVoleModel DeserializeData(string data)
    {
        var result = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert
                    .DeserializeObject<Models.BadgeVoleModel>(data);

        return result;
    }
```